# Le verbe compétiter

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, choix-de-mot, néologismes, académie-française

> Compétiter est un hybride du verbe anglais to compete, « être en
> concurrence avec ; concourir », et des noms français compétition et
> compétiteur. Ce verbe est assez étrange pour n’être employé, jusqu’à
> présent, qu’à l’infinitif, mais, même à ce mode, il convient de le
> bannir et de le remplacer par une des nombreuses formes déjà en usage
> qu’offre le français.
>
> On dit
>
> - Demain je participerai à une compétition
> - Il prendra part au saut en longueur
>
> One ne dit pas
>
> - Demain je vais compétiter
> - Il va compétiter au saut en longueur

http://www.academie-francaise.fr/competiter

Je ne comprends pas quel est le problème que pose ce verbe. Il me semble pouvoir combler une lacune.

> je participerai à une compétition (5 mots !) versus je vais compétiter (3 mots)

D'ailleurs, je compétite, tu compétites, je compétiterai, etc. Quel obstacle présenterait sa conjugaison ?

Comment: 1/ So as to be consistent, you should write "compétiterai" instead. 2/ http://www.academie-francaise.fr/un-probleme-ou-un-souci 3/ …ne comprend pas le problème que pose ce verbe

Comment: Note that,  in English,  "Je vais participer à une compétition." would not in any case be translated by "I'm going to compete.", but by "I'm going to take part in a competition.".

Comment: Compte plutôt les syllabes: *(demain) je participerai à une compétition* 12 syllabes, *(demain) je vais compétiter* 6 syllabes. Ce qui se dit: *(demain) j'ai compète* 3 syllabes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il n'est pas du tout clair pourquoi ce nouveau verbe serait indésirable dans le vocabulaire du français; malheureusement le « dictat » de l'Académie ne nous renseigne pas sur la philosophie qui motive leur décision et il serait nécessaire de bien savoir d'abord ce que les académiciens reprochent à ce terme. On trouve ce mot déjà au 17ième siècle dans la [langue de Molière](https://books.google.fr/books?id=QZc9AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA287&dq=%22comp%C3%A9titer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwimz8Tb8vXuAhVaAWMBHaoxBQAQ6AEwBnoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22comp%C3%A9titer%22&f=false), plus particulièrement dans bouche de l'un des acteurs qui interprètent les comédies, un acteur nommé Gros-René ; cependant, en ce temps-là ce mot n'est pas reconnu.

[image]

Il  est dit faire partie du galimatias de Gros-René dans cette [source](https://books.google.fr/books?id=-H1nbAktV_YC&pg=PA441&dq=%22comp%C3%A9titer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwimz8Tb8vXuAhVaAWMBHaoxBQAQ6AEwAXoECEwQAg#v=onepage&q=%22comp%C3%A9titer%22&f=false), et donc, n'avoir aucun sens bien précis.

Ce verbe est utilisé dans certains articles, ([article 1](https://educationpositive-oze.fr/2019/10/26/esprit-de-competition-developpement-enfant/),[article 2](https://sante.lefigaro.fr/actualite/2011/06/26/10977-lesprit-competition-est-il-si-bon)) où il est encore soigneusement introduit entre guillemets.
Néanmoins, le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/comp%C3%A9titer) reconnait ce verbe et prévient qu'il est rarement employé. Il a pour synonyme « *compétitionner* », mais au Québec, et en France, « concurrencer ».